# play framekwork 2.2. - ebean model save time from request

Tags: angularjs, validation, time, playframework-2.0, ebean

i have these model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipe")
public class Recipe extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Constraints.Required
    public String title;

    @Column(name = "short_description")
    public String shortDescription;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    public String ingredients;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    public String cooking;

    @NotNull
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="HH:mm:ss")
    public Time time;
```

now i'd like to save data comming from angular js with restangular. all parameters were provieded in the controller but i get a error:

```
{"time":["Invalid value"]}
```

all data were strings in the request. i guess thats the problem. but i don't want cast it by my self, because then i loose the play form validation...
do you can give me any hints?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java and dates/times do not play nice together unfortunately. I would remove the `@Formats` annotation and just pass in the 'unix time' because that is what the `Time` class expects. You can do this pretty easily on the angular side by implementing the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library. if you are getting the dates in the format `HH:mm:ss` then in your angular controller use the following code to format the time to unix time:

```
var time = moment(str, "HH:mm:ss").format("X");
```

where `str` is a string represtation of the time you are formatting. then pass `time` in as the parameter.

if i completely misunderstood the question and you are retrieving the time from the database and not saving the time to the database then just flip the above method.

```
var time = moment(str, "X").format("HH:mm:ss");
```

where `str` is the time you retrieved from the database.